# Which animal that lives in the forest makes this noise?

Tags: zoology, ethology, communication

Which animal makes this noise? [Link to audio file](https://clyp.it/1xtf1cif)

The file was recorded next to a forest in Germany.

Comment: You might get lucky, but noise to animal mapping is rare indeed.  Your recording is only picking up the higher frequencies this animal made, and I know a few human animals that can make a variety of non-human animal noises :)  Good luck with it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is a bird sound and most probaby a young bird of prey. It might be a young buzzard. Or, if it's in the eveving or night it might be the sound of a young owl.